# "awk" Command Behaves Differently On SuSE 11 vs. Solaris 10

Tags: awk, ksh, behavior, suse, solaris-10

Friends,

I'm trying to extract the last part of following path in a ksh script:

```
TOOL_HOME=/export/fapps/mytool/mytool-V2-3-4
```

I want to extract the version # (i.e., 2-3-4) from the above.

awk runs fine on SuSE:

```
echo $TOOL_HOME | awk -F'mytool-V' '{print $2}'
#2-3-4
```

However, on Solaris 10, it produces the following:

```
#ytool
```

So on Solaris, awk is ignoring everything after the first character in -F'mytool-V'

What should i do to get the same output on both OS's?

Comment: Where's the `#` sign in the output coming from? It doesn't exist in the input and you aren't adding it in the `print` statement so why does it exist in your output? Which awk are you executing on Solaris - /bin/awk or /bin/nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk? (hint - you SHOULD be using the last one in the list as the first one is old, broken awk and the second one is just pre-POSIX).

Comment: I just added # to show that that's my output, i don't actually get it on the screen. Regarding which awk, let me check and get back

Comment: Don't add stuff that doesn't exist. That's like taking your car to the mechanic to diagnose your car pulling to the left and puncturing your left front tire before you show it to him to ask for what he thinks might be the problem.

Comment: Looks like a simple enough job for `sed` IMHO.

Comment: Go back to @EdMorton's comment and make sure you're using the later version of awk. Old, broken awk only takes a single character for the field separator (in your case `m`) and ignores the rest as you're seeing.

Comment: @Ed Morton - /usr/xpg4/bin/awk worked! You may want to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @JimitRaithatha  OK, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solaris `awk` is broken...

```
$ echo "$TOOL_HOME" | awk '{sub(/.*mytool-V/,"")}1'
2-3-4
```

or simply with `sed`

```
$ echo "$TOOL_HOME" | sed 's/.*mytool-V//'
2-3-4
```

Comment: awk isn't broken on Solaris. /bin/awk on Solaris is old, broken awk and so should never be used but neither /bin/nawk nor /usr/xpg4/bin/awk on Solaris are broken and in fact /usr/xpg4/bin/awk is even very close to POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 2):

On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, not /bin/awk (aka "old, broken awk").

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `awk` or any other external program. `ksh` can do that:

```
echo ${TOOL_HOME##*mytool-V}
```

Comment: Michael, your code still returns the whole path instead of just the last part